# How do aggregate functions in work in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Something piqued my curiosity (no problem in my code though, just a general question). How do aggregate functions in SQL Serverreally work? What are the mechanics behind it?

Let's say we got a table of 999,999,999 rows, and we want to obtain only the number of rows in this table.

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   <Table>
```

Will this aggregate function scan through the entire table, row by row, to get the amount of rows in this table, or is there an internal table keeping track of the amount of rows within it when rows are added/ removed from this table (accessed through a system stored procedure) and will functions like these use more CPU or would it use more I/O Read/Write time?

P.S. I read [This MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx), but it did not answer my question unfortunately.

Thanks

Comment: count(*) without conditions just asks row count from table (clustered index) metadata. It almost doesn't consume CPU neither I/O. Of course when you add some conditions, then things change dramatically.

Comment: @Arvo Put this as an answer. This is what I wanted to know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick note: `count(*)` in SQL Server does **not** interrogate metadata. **Querying metadata for `count(*)` is completely incorrect when you consider isolation levels and row visibility of ucommitted transactions**. Besides the metadata row count can drift from actual row count under certain conditions (more in old versions, fewer in newer versions). The specific conditions are irelevant, but consider *why* [`DBCC UPDATEUSAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188414.aspx) has a `COUNT_ROWS` clause:

> Specifies that the row count column is updated with the current count of the number of rows in the table or view.

That being said, how are aggregates being implemented? First I would recommend reading up about the [Volcano](http://paperhub.s3.amazonaws.com/dace52a42c07f7f8348b08dc2b186061.pdf) execution model. Is a lengthy paper, but is critical in understanding the row-by-row execution model of most relational databases. Next I recommend reading this blog post [Stream Aggregate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/09/13/752728.aspx). The gist of it that stream aggregates require a *sorted* input and on a sorted input is very easy to compute any aggregate (btw. there are well known one-pass algorithms for [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance), the only one that does not have an obvious trivial implementation).

For completeness here is the link to the streaming aggregates <strike>ugly sister</strike> memory hog alternative: the [Hash Aggregates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/09/20/hash-aggregate.aspx).

Comment: this.  This is why I love developing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It will run and index scan if possible, if not it will run a table scan.

```
Set SHOWPLAN_TEXT on
go
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   <Table>
```